# how to cancel an automatic restart in windows server 2012 after installing windows updates

Tags: windows-server-2012, automatic-updates, shutdown

Here's the thing - the "shutdown -a" option doesn't work, there is no "Restart Later" button, just a countdown timer of 15 minutes and no way to cancel it.

What should I do? I read somewhere that if I lock, it will freeze the timer until my next logon, but I don't wanna wait until "the time is right".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The timer is part of the windows update service not the OS itself so you can stop it by stopping the service try `net stop "windows update"`that should do the trick.

But this is a temp solution since the service will start again when you reboot later, I guess what you really want is forcing the Windows to do the restart at the update scheduling time, basically you need to add a registry entry to do so, try this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835627

Comment: stopping the service is a good temporary solution so thank you for that. What I eventually did is disable the service and set automatic updates off.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the PSWindowsUpdate powershell module. It allows you to ignore reboots.

```
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot
```

If you get error "The specified module 'PSWindowsUpdate' was not loaded because no valid module file was found..." you may need to download and install it with this script.

```
$webDeployURL = "https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc/file/41459/43/PSWindowsUpdate.zip"
$filePath = "$($env:TEMP)\PSWindowsUpdate.zip"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($webDeployURL, $filePath)
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$zipFile = $shell.NameSpace($filePath)
$destinationFolder = $shell.NameSpace("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules")
$copyFlags = 0x00
$copyFlags += 0x04 # Hide progress dialogs
$copyFlags += 0x10 # Overwrite existing files
$destinationFolder.CopyHere($zipFile.Items(), $copyFlags)
# Clean up
Remove-Item -Force -Path $filePath
Import-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```